# Symfony command with a constructor not found

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to make my code ready to update to Symfony4. 
To do this, I want to refactor commands to get private services. 
I looked into the documentation and I have to add a constructor in the command.
When I do this, I can't use the command because it is saying that no command exists with that name whereas it is working when I remove the constructor.

Command :

```
class CorrectionReponseCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('correction:reponse')
            ->setDescription('Calcule les notes de chaque réponse.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```
services:
     _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

     App\CorrectionReponseCommand:
        public: true
        tags:
           - { name: 'console.command', command: 'correction:response' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Symfony 4.x, all services are created using autowiring/autoconfigure and are private by default.

You should check your services' configuration file, and add `public: true` to your Command definiton, explicitly or tag it.

```
# config/services.yaml
# ...

services:
    # ...

    App\CorrectionReponseCommand:
        # ...
        public: true
        tags:
            - { name: 'console.command', command: 'app:correction:response' }
```

More information [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#the-new-default-services-yaml-file).

Comment: I'm still using Symfony 3.4.
In my services.yml, I have this : `_defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false`

Comment: So, you should set it public explicitly. Could you show us your service definition file?

Comment: It is working with your config. Thanks a lot ! I'm still asking myself a question : is it recommended to make commands public services ?